# custom ubuntu distro

Tags: system, customization

I have an standar ubuntu 18.04 installation plus many handmade applications developped by myself.

I need a way to create some sort of installer which will make the same thing as a bootable media installer but will install (and configure) my own applications as well.

PS: I need it for quick deployment.

Comment: Makulu Linux (based on Ubuntu) has a 'constructor' that builds an ISO from your currently used setup. It's not alone, as there are many. I've not used any, just thought the Makulu script looked pretty useful & cool (it's open source too)

Comment: Use the debian live scripts. They are in the repositories and despite the name make an ubuntu install. https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/index.en.html